# How to see definition of the built-in functions in SQL

Tags: sql-server

In SQL Server ,We can script User defined function using script as option by right clicking on the function name in SQL Server Management Studio,Like wise how to see the definition of built in function by using SQL Script any options are there ?

I want to see the definition of Meta Data build in function like object_definition,IdentityProperty etc.Can i able to script or view the definition of these functions ?

Comment: Why do you need to know the inner workings of built in functions? Unless you can get the C++ source code there isn't a lot you can do. Honestly you don't need to know the source code, you just need to understand them.

Answer (score 1):

Well if it's a stored function then you can use `sp_helptext` to see the body like below else there is no way you can see the body/definition of the function [AFAIK]

```
sp_helptext 'object_definition'
```

Comment: Thanks for you response.I will check with this now.

Comment: Hi Rahul ,sp_helptext is not working for 'Object_Definition' and 'IdentityProperty ' any other way is there ?

Comment: @AbinashKumar, read the answer carefully. I said if it's a stored function then only `sp_helptext` can be used. Here for example, `Object_Definition` is not a stored function and so, there is no way you can see it's body.

Comment: Thank You for your reply.I understood now.

Comment: @AbinashKumar, Welcome, consider accepting the answer if it helped.